# How do I build Android Emulator from the source?

Tags: android, build, emulation, android-source

I'd like to modify (for now, adding more logs on the guest and host sides) the Android Emulator, which I guess is mostly available in [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com).

My understanding (or rather, imagination) is that the Android Emulator may have 4 components:

1. The modified kernel
2. The guest components such as remote forwarding of the opengl API calls, etc
3. The host-side services that implements whatever remote calls (remote graphics API, remote modem-related HAL API if any, etc)
4. The "emulator" binary that may read the (set of) image files (such as system.img?), render the guest frames, takes the user inputs to deliver them to the guest, etc

I imagine that 1 is in a separate repository and might be given as a commandline argument or so to the emulator. I think 2 and 3 are probably in the `AOSP` tree and I might need the right target/configuration. I have no idea about 4 -- as 4 is now in the prebuilt directory as an executable.

I cannot find the full build instructions for all of the 4 components. I found some but they seem to be outdated, and did not work with the most recent `aosp/main` branch. For example, [this](https://utzcoz.github.io/2019/06/16/Build-AOSP-for-emulator.html) explains how to build the emulator binary, which is in the prebuilt directory of `aosp` now. Although the article says that I should `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug`, the target does not appear to exist anymore.

I simply ran `lunch`, which shows the list of supported targets. However, there's none that has `goldfish` or `ranchu` or `emulator` in it. There are a few that starts with `sdk` but all are `sdk_car_*`. They don't seem to be relevant.

What's the process to build the required Android Emulator components? I am using Linux (Debian), and used to build android images here. I cannot, however, figure out how we should build emulator, its kernel, and the images that the emulator would run.

Comment: Note your blog link has: `I change target to aosp_x86_64, and emulator works fine in my work machine with architecture x86_64` Also see: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building#choose-a-target

Comment: The blog did not specifically say what's the `repo init` command (especially the manifest branch). Thus, I used the default value, which I think is `main`. Then, `lunch` menu did not list the said value, `sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug`. The `lunch` command on the menu did not work as is.

Comment: You can use a stable branch/tag for `repo init` like `android-14.0.0_r28`.

Answer (score 0):

According to a SWE at Google, who appears to work on Goldfish, the lunch target has changed to:
`sdk_phone64_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug`.

And, the lunch menu item somehow did not show up on a mere `lunch` command.

According to the same SWE, Goldfish does not seem to modify the kernel, or "share the kernel with Cuttlefish." I assume that the prebuilt kernel would work.

The manifest branch for the emulator is `emu-master-dev`. The build instruction appears to be:

```
$ cd external/qemu
$ ./android/rebuild.sh --gfxstream
$ ls ./objs/emulator
```